# Angular ngModelOptions allowInvalid not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

i have code like this, where i set options `{allowInvalid: true}`

```
<input type="number" name="userName"
         ng-model="user.name"
         ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"
         ng-blur="test(user)"/>
```

When i input non number value into non number, example: `abc`,
why `user.name` still changed to `undefined`?
where i expected the model `user.name` should be `'abc'`.

Full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/BsLk2GWVkchNgKaOV453?p=preview
i'm using angular v1.3.16

Comment: because you use `type="number"` in this case for invalid input - value is _undefined_

Comment: Following the https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D, you can't use `allowInvalid` with `type="number"` attribute

Comment: @grundy that were the purpose. i use `allowInvalid: true`. So if i input invalid value. it's should not change value to undefined :(

Comment: see more in @Kosta comment :-)

Comment: @Kosta thanks man. you have answered the question. can you please put that as answer so i can accept it. thanks :)

Comment: In my experience you should never use type="number" for non mobile apps. It absolutely has no value to the user.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following the [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D), you can't use `allowInvalid` with `type="number"` attribute.

> ## Issues with HTML5 constraint validation
>
> In browsers that follow [the HTML5 specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29), `input[number]` does not work as expected with `ngModelOptions.allowInvalid`. If a non-number is entered in the input, the browser will report the value as an empty string, which means the view / model values in ngModel and subsequently the scope value will also be an empty string.